# Histogram by categories with counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

The data I have been given already has the total counts for the categories.  I am trying to make a histogram of the number of houses for each com and age where Houses is the total count for that category.

```
Com<-c( "Newport",  "Newport",  "Newport",  "Newport",  "Newport",  "Newport",  "Topeka",   "Topeka",   "Topeka",   "Topeka",   "Topeka",   "Topeka",   "Missoula", "Missoula", "Missoula", "Missoula", "Missoula", "Missoula"  )
Age<-c( "1970s",    "1960s",    "1950s",    "1940s",    "1940_earlier", "1990s",    "1970s",    "1960s",    "1950s",    "1940s",    "1940_earlier", "1990s",    "1970s",    "1960s",    "1950s",    "1940s",    "1940_earlier", "1990s" )
Houses<-c(  11, 6,  3,  0,  0,  21, 44, 0,  3,  3,  25, 20, 0,  51, 236,    192,    312,    299 )
df=data.frame(Com,Age,Houses)
```

So df is the data

```
histogram( ~ Age | Com, data=df)
```

I have also tried

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2) 
g <- ggplot(df$counts, aes(df$Age))
g + geom_bar()
```

Also

```
barplot(prop.table(table(df$Age)))
```

And lastly

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Age)) 
p <- p + geom_histogram(aes(weights=Houses, fill=Com))
p <- p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3")
p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ Com, ncol=1)
p
```

Here is my R version information:

```
R.Version()

$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
$arch
[1] "x86_64"
$os
[1] "mingw32"
$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"
$status
[1] ""
$major
[1] "3"
$minor
[1] "3.0"
$year
[1] "2016"
$month
[1] "05"
$day
[1] "03"
$`svn rev`
[1] "70573"
$language
[1] "R"
$version.string
[1] "R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)"
$nickname
[1] "Supposedly Educational"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `geom_bar()` in `ggplot2` with totals that have already been computed (rather than needing to count or sum cases), you need to specify `stat="identity"`. How about

```
g0 <- ggplot(df,aes(Age,Houses))+
   geom_bar(stat="identity")+
   facet_wrap(~Com)
print(g0)
```

? or

```
ggplot(df,aes(Age,Houses))+
   geom_bar(stat="identity")+
   coord_flip()+
   facet_wrap(~Com,ncol=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The lattice function is barchart:

```
library(lattice)
barchart( Houses ~ Age ,group=Com,  data=df)
```

The base barplot solution requires that the data be in a matrix, table or xtabs object. By defatul you get a stacke bar plot but if you wnat the same as the lattice code above you add the beside argument:

```
barplot(xtabs(Houses~Com+Age, data=df), beside=TRUE)
```